# Image Hover Effects For Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to find an image hover effect that is similar to this website. http://themeforest.net/item/city-college/full_screen_preview/235957

There are 3 images with title on the bottom and when you move your mouse over one of the image, there will be a description and "read more" link .

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hover/?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into a similar need:

jQuery Tutorial:
http://buildinternet.com/2009/03/sliding-boxes-and-captions-with-jquery/

jQuery Plugin:
http://buildinternet.com/2011/03/mosaic-sliding-boxes-and-captions-jquery-plugin/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a plugin. This [one](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-visual-slidebox-builder/) does that